# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot compile with STLport

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stl

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

I downloaded the source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/, extracting at a path.read the INSTALL.unixes.

step:

1. ./configure
2. make && make check

error:
`../../../test/unit/iota.h:10:30: error: ‘iota’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]`

`iota(__first, __last, __val);`
`In file included from ../../../stlport/numeric:33:0,
from ../../../test/unit/iter_test.cpp:4:
../../../stlport/stl/_numeric.h:174:6: note: ‘template<class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> void stlp_std::iota(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Tp)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
 void iota(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Tp __val) {`

Do I have miss something.Thank you.

Comment: What I want to do is using STLport replace the default STL, making the gcc(g++) using STLport compile my program.

Comment: Firstly, you can go and edit your question if you find a way to clarify it, don't use comments for that. Then, I wonder why? STLport was great when compilers didn't have proper C++ standard library implementations (calling those STLs is downright wrong, see the description of the STL tag!), but those days are gone. Currently, it is rather a step downward, because the last release was made 2008!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In _numeric.h file, I find the definition and a comment  "// iota is not part of the C++ standard.  It is an extension.".Do you mean this.

Comment: The question is why you think you need STLport. If you can't answer that, let me assure you that you *don't* need it!

Comment: I want to read the SGI STL sources.If  gcc compile my program with STLport, I can modify the header files and understand easily.In my opinion the default STL in ubuntu is not easy to understand.

Comment: @stonecutter - Specifically about `iota`: It wasn't part of the standard when STLport was active, but it is now. So you are not learning current C++.

Comment: @BoPersson I get it .I have checked the file where error appear, but I found that file including the definition of iota, I just can't figure out what's wrong. Maybe I have miss something. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Development of the STL stopped more than ten years ago, it is nowadays only historically relevant. Please, believe me that you don't even know what the STL is, which shows in the way you use that term. Check out the description for the "stl" tag as a starting point.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for your advice, I have started as what you said.